# another openssl on windows problem that VERIFY_NONE doesn't help

Tags: ruby, openssl, youtube-api, rest-client

I am trying to make a little ruby script to upload my own video And here's the complete code, it's pretty short:

```
    require 'openssl'
    OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # warning: already initialized constant VERIFY_PEER \n 0 
    require 'youtube_it'
    require 'rest-client'

    # Authentication
    auth_devkey      = '...'
    auth_user        = '...'
    auth_pass        = '...'

    # Getting auth token
    response    = RestClient.post "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", {:Email => auth_user, :Passwd => auth_pass, :service => "youtube", :source => "..."}, :content_type => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    auth_token  = response[/(?<=auth=).*/i]
    # so far so good

    # creating a new youtube_it client
    yt_client   = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:username => auth_user, :password =>  auth_pass, :dev_key => auth_devkey)
    # A-Okay


    # Uploading video
    vpath       = "c:/downloads/videos/video.mov"
    upload_response = yt_client.video_upload(File.open(vpath), :title => "test",:description => 'some description', :category => 'People',:keywords => %w[cool blah test], :list => 'denied')

    # big error here
    OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:677:in `connect'
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:677:in `connect'
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1160:in `request'
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:17:in `request'
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:970:in `post'
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/youtube_it-1.4.1/lib/youtube_it/request/video_upload.rb:525:in `auth_token'
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/youtube_it-1.4.1/lib/youtube_it/request/video_upload.rb:463:in `authorization_hea
    ders'
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/youtube_it-1.4.1/lib/youtube_it/request/video_upload.rb:94:in `upload'
            from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/youtube_it-1.4.1/lib/youtube_it/client.rb:99:in `video_upload'
            from (irb):81
            from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I am sure if I can immediately supply any other information and I might miss pasting here and that is needed to solve this. I don't want to ask questions here lightly without googling at least 4 hours,but I can't find anything helpful.

Thanks a billion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi guys this errors was fixed in the last version of youtube_it, you can see here

https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/commit/032f2800ae4c4ab9f6000b23150e3a8d3517815f

regards!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you cannot do this:

```
   OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

you have to modify the :verify_mode attribute of the SSLContext instance.
you can try to get the instance variable of the NET::HTTP object via instance_variable_get inside the rest-client and then set the :verify_mode accordingly.

the better way is to directly set the :verify_ssl attribute of the rest-client itself:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :post, :url => 'http://example.com', :verify_ssl => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE )
```

for further reading i suggest to look at the source code [here](https://github.com/adamwiggins/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/request.rb)

Comment: Hey ALoR, before anything, thanks for writing back -- I went into the that youtube_it gem's folder and did a dir wide search of ssl and found and did this
      http.use_ssl = true
      http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
and it workeD!!
However, I will be uploading this app to heroku and it is heroku that will install the gem which means I can't go inside the gem to fix it up myself, what will I do then? Why do they even bother with this SSL thing if everyone's trying to shut down the verifcation from all the posts I can find on google?

Comment: don't try to modify the gem itself, try to find a way as i described for the rest-client to modify the value from your code.  everyone is shutting down the verify because they are lazy and don't want to implement it in the correct way. the certificates should always be checked. ssl without verification is like a photocopy of your driver license: same information as the original one, but with no value at all... :)

Comment: I see. I will try that. No chance you have any tutorial links handy about how to set up the SSL cert? How perhaps a suggestion of what keyword to look up on google as I suspect this is a very wide ranged topic and it might take quite a bit of digging..Thanks!